# content in html template is being replaced by template's file-location and not desired text

Tags: html, templates, go, web-frameworks

I'm using the html/template package to serve a template on submission of the form. The page that is a copy of that template is being rendered with the location of the template-file instead of the text that should replace {{ .Title }}

So in response.html, the {{ .Title }} is showing up as "Projects/Go/src/web/site/index" instead of "I feel that is "

How can I get the {{ .Title }} to be replaced by the text and not the file-location?

Here is my code:

```
package main


import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/zenazn/goji"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"

    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
)


type Page struct {
    Title string
    Body []byte
}


func loadPage(title string) (*Page, error){
    filename := title + ".html"
    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil{
       return nil, err
    }
    return &Page{Title: title, Body: body}, nil 
}


 func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, p *Page){
     t, err := template.ParseFiles(tmpl + ".html")

 if err != nil{
     panic(err)
 }

 err = t.Execute(w, p)
     fmt.Println(err)
}


func response(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    p, err := loadPage("Projects/Go/src/web/site/index")
    if err != nil{
        p = &Page{Title: "I feel that is "}
        panic(err)
    }
    renderTemplate(w, "Projects/Go/src/web/site/response", p)
}


func serveSingle(filename string) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
         http.ServeFile(w, r, filename)
     }
}


 func main() {
     goji.Get("/", serveSingle("Projects/Go/src/web/site/index.html"))
     goji.Handle("/ask", response)
     goji.Serve()
}
```

Comment: Your `loadPage()` function sets the title of the page to the `title` variable, which is set to `Projects/Go/src/web/site/index` on the first line of your `response` function.

Comment: Also, you're only setting the `Title` to "I feel that is " if `err != nil`. This is probably not correct. Try changing the `p = &Page{Title: "I feel that is "}` line to `p.Title = "I feel that is "` and moving it outside the error check block.

Comment: @intermernet it is more complex than just that string. I made it that simple for the question's sake.

Comment: @Intermernet Thank you for pointing that out. That fixed it. May you post that as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `loadPage()` function sets `Page.Title` to the file path, minus the `.html` extension by default.

You are only overriding this default behaviour in your `response()` function when `err != nil`. You're also completely overriding the `p` variable with the line `p = &Page{Title: "I feel that is "}` instead of just setting the `Title` field on the existing `Page`.

You should try changing:

```
func response(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    p, err := loadPage("Projects/Go/src/web/site/index")
    if err != nil{
        p = &Page{Title: "I feel that is "}
        panic(err)
    }
    renderTemplate(w, "Projects/Go/src/web/site/response", p)
}
```

To:

```
func response(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    p, err := loadPage("Projects/Go/src/web/site/index")
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    p.Title = "I feel that is "
    renderTemplate(w, "Projects/Go/src/web/site/response", p)
}
```